# How to get total number of Tweets (just counts of tweets)

Tags: twitter4j

Is there any possibility to get total number of tweets (just count of tweets ) of particular user. If user X poster 10000 tweets then code return just total number of tweets not actually tweets with text or anything. I am looking for it in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an `User u` you can use `u.getStatusesCount()` to get the total number of tweets